# jQuery conflict MooTools in Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

I want to add a jQuery slider to my Joomla website but the slider is not working. After some time, I found the issue: jQuery and MooTools conflict. I googled the issue but I can't fix it.

**jQuery Script:**

```
<script>
     jQuery.noConflict();

   </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

I have placed this script at the end of the body tag. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: would you like to share your site url so i can look for any solution...

Answer (score 4):

Put the `jQuery.noConflict()` *after* you include the jquery.min.js, otherwise `jQuery` is not defined.

I'm not familiar with flexslider, but if it is a well-behaved plugin it will work after `.noConflict()`.

(Without seeing more of your code I can't guess whether there are other problems.)

Answer (score 0):

Pu the script in the head tag and inside `js\jquery.flexslider-min.js` put `$.noConflict()` and inside the `(function()` put `$` inside the parentheses.

P.S. Please post the contents of jquery.flexslider-min.js